# How can i wait till page reload

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script using selenium in python, in which I am fetching a  webpage checking some element value and clicking on a button. after I am clicking on the button certain elements value change and the page is reloaded for next iteration.

My question is how do I wait for the for to reload properly and then go to next iteration

For now I,am using

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Or

Again loading the page

```
driver.get(url)
```

Can anyone tell me a workaround.. coz i didn't find any function in webdriver to wait for form reload.

Comment: But here the scenario is the element are already present as i the same form is loaded again

Comment: As stated in the related **question**, webdriver already waits for page load, unless the page is loaded dynamically with **`ajax`**. In that case, wait for the element to be present before clicking it, using the method in the related question's answer.